# Review of code for generating combinations of numbers

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, combinations

Can anyone show me how I can generate all possible combinations of numbers? For example, if I have this `arrayOfNumbers = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16;`

I need to generate as many six-number combinations as possible.

These combinations are same to me `1,2,3,4,5,6 == 1,3,2,5,4,6;`

I come up with some pretty easy code, but I would like to make this code much better. Can I do this somehow without declaring `maximumPossibilities`? Total numbers may be different at times, it can be from 1 to 48;  And `countOfNumbersForPlay` may be different, from 6 to 11;

```
+ (NSArray *)generateNumbers{

    int MAX_POSSIBILITIES = 7;
    int COUNT_OF_NUMS_FOR_PLAY = 6;

    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array]; 

    NSArray *numbers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], [NSNumber numberWithInt:4], [NSNumber numberWithInt:5], [NSNumber numberWithInt:6], [NSNumber numberWithInt:7], nil];

    int i = 0;
    do {

        int x = 0;

        NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray array];

        do {

            int randomIndex = rand() % numbers.count;

            if (![temp containsObject:[numbers objectAtIndex:randomIndex]]) {
                [temp addObject:[numbers objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
                x++;
            }

        } while (x < COUNT_OF_NUMS_FOR_PLAY);

        NSArray *sortedArray = [temp sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
            if ([obj1 intValue] < [obj2 intValue]) {
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            } else if ([obj1 intValue] > [obj2 intValue]) {
                return NSOrderedDescending;
            } else {
                return NSOrderedSame;
            }
        }];


        if (![results containsObject:sortedArray]) {
            [results addObject:sortedArray];
            i++;
        }

    } while (i < MAX_POSSIBILITIES);    

    return results;
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination - is that what you want?

Comment: yes that what i need, but how i can do that in xcode c++? My solution is not good enough for me.

Comment: Does this sound like homework to anyone else?

Comment: No you don't have to make here exact code i just need a littel help, how i can improve my code. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you just count from 012345 to 456789 you will have passed through all of the possible combinations for the digits 0..9.  And any number where an earlier digit is equal to or larger than a later digit (eg, 103456) it already "covered", given your rules, so you can skip from, eg, 200000 in your count to 234567.

It's a fairly simple matter from there to generalize for arbitrary "digits".  Create an array to hold your "digits".  Each array element is one "digit".  Then you need to implement the increment rule (just like ordinary arithmetic) that when a digit is incremented beyond its upper bound it is reset to its lower bound and a "carry" causes the next higher-order digit to be incremented.  But note that when you increment in this fashion, the new value of the current digit will be inevitably less than the digit that you just incremented to the left (unless it also was incremented to past its upper bound), so you must set the current digit to the value of the digit to the left + 1, and set the digits to the right to increasing values after the current digit.

The results of each increment is one of the values to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Although Daniel gives a similar solution above, I'd like to phrase it in this way because this is how I conceptually view this kind of problem.

Assume you have an 'alphabet' of the characters called `alpha`, let's say alpha = {1,2,3,4,5,6} for this example. The length of the alphabet in this case is 6.

You understand that you will have 6^k valid k-length numbers with this alphabet. Because of you ensuring that all the characters are unique, it's only really possible to check

Basically for all i in [0..6^k] just convert i to base to 6. If you had a non-numerical alphabet, you can now translate each character to it's alphabet's index.